# Three table MySQL LEFT JOIN not returning rows where one table isn't involved

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database that stores people's **orders**.

**orders** may contain:

- tickets (or no tickets),
- pledge_type_id (or no pledge_type_id)

An **order** may have just an **additional_donation** amount an **NO tickets (tickets.order_=order_id) and NO pledge (pledge_type_id)**. It should still display...

### THE PROBLEM:

However, **orders with no tickets** (that have either a **pledge_type_id** or **pledge_type_id=0 and additional_donation=[some number]**) are *not displaying*.

How can I modify this query to return those rows?

Thanks!

```
SELECT 
o.order_id, o.name_f, o.name_l, o.email, 
COUNT( * ) AS num_tix, 
h.name_f, h.name_l, 
o.additional_donation, 
p.title, p.price, 
o.donation_monthly_YN, 
o.process_step, 
o.paid_status_YNVRD

FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN tickets t ON t.order_id = o.order_id
LEFT JOIN HOSTS h ON h.host_id = o.host_id
LEFT JOIN pledge_types p ON p.pledge_type_id = o.pledge_type_id

WHERE o.gala_id =  '1'
GROUP BY o.order_id
ORDER BY o.deleted_YN ASC , datetime_created DESC
```

Here's a fiddle: sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ea71/1

(It won't allow meto upload data (too big) so here's the sql for the db+data:   http://cypgala.com/developer_notes/cypgala_experimental_db.sql (I replaced real names/emails w/fakes))

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with this query. Are you sure that the query is the problem? If you are, consider providing a sqlfiddle.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, because there are rows in **orders** that display when you do a SELECT on just **orders** but not when you start looking for either pledges or tickets (as above). Thanks.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ea71/1 thanks!

Comment: Um, there's no data in your sqlfiddle!?! Provide some sample data, just enough to be properly representative, together with your expected output. Use made up data if it's sensitive.

Comment: (It won't allow me to upload data (too big) so here's the sql for the db+data: http://cypgala.com/developer_notes/cypgala_experimental_db.sql (I replaced real names/emails w/fakes))

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have in one of those tables (hosts or pledge_types) a corresponding tuple for that order. Try RIGHT JOIN on those tables.

Comment: Seems like RIGHT JOIN eliminates more rows.

Comment: There you go! Just put the RIGHT JOIN on the right side (no pun intendend), and voilà!

Comment: I've imported your data and ran some tests. It looks like it is working fine. You have 147 orders. And even with the JOIN's, you're getting 147 orders. The only thing odd I noticed is that you have duplicated orders, that show up when you remove the GROUP BY clause.